# Cocos2D Help: How to update cocos2d from 1.0.1 to 2.0 rc1 properly?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I had cocos2D version 1.0.1 and I installed cocos2D latest version 2.0 rc1 with help from this website:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/ad-hoc-beta-testing/75910-how-install-cocos2d-xcode.html

Now when I go inside cocos2d/cocos2d.m I see the version as follows:

```
static NSString *version = @"cocos2d v1.0.1";
```

Does this mean that my version is still 1.0.1 and not 2.0 rc1?

Another thing I want to ask is that I am trying to learn Box2d from raywenderlich's blog:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls

When I create a new box2d project and erase all coded to start from scratch, I followed the tutorial and tried to code but then it shows errors that the methods and classes are not recognised. Such as when I make a new b2World object the constructor is not recognised. Is this because of the conflict of cocos2d versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to upgrade cocos2d in an existing project.](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/05/update-cocos2d-iphone-existing-project/) The most crucial step is to **delete** all cocos2d files before copying the new version over, otherwise you may end up with a mix of old and new files.

Keep in mind that Box2D has also been upgraded to v2.2 I believe whereas cocos2d v1.0 ships with Box2D v2.1. There were some changes to the Box2D API as well. Those are easy to fix if you look at the Box2D template projects and consult the [Box2D API reference](http://learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/Box2D/html/index.html).

Comment: So can you tell me how to delete cocos2D completely so that I can install a fresh version of ver 2.0 rc1 please?

Comment: Read the tutorial. You need to delete all the cocos2d files from your project. It has nothing to do with installing, each cocos2d project uses its own copy of the cocos2d source code.